Managing controllers for identical entity structures?
I am developing a Spring Boot app and I am faced with the following situation:
I have x and y entities, but the fields of these entities are exactly the same, and because of this they both use the same DTO (the only difference is that they have different names and both have their own database tables). This situation results that I currently have two identical controllers.
For business reasons, they have to be two separate entities, even though they are the same fields.
What is the correct procedure in this case?
Even though it is code duplication, do I keep both controllers so that one controller can be responsible for only one entity?
Or can I somehow make it so that I can use one controller for both entities, with a dynamic path, and by highlighting the entity type in the path, I can differentiate which service implementation it uses (because the service interface is the same, the two implementations differ in a few details, and one goes to table x and the other to the table y)?

If they are two separate business entities, then it's better to have two separate controllers. For example, the first one could have a request mapping /customers, and the second one could be /companies. You can create some generic DTO class given that the two entities share common fields.
Also, you can go with one controller method and declare a path variable for the entity type (/api/{entityType}, for example if you're dealing with customers, then the entityType's value would be "customers", etc.) . Upon receiving a request, you would check the entity's type and delegate to an appropriate service class that encapsulates the business logic related to the called entity.

Two separate business entities, in a way that they are both auction items, but one is one type and the other is different, although they happen to contain the same fields, but I still have to treat them as two separate entities. In this case, is it better to have two separate controllers? I wanted to try what you described second, however I asked the question elsewhere and no one thought it was a good idea to merge the controllers in this way.

Yes, I believe if they are separate business entities then you have to create a controller for each. Having separate controllers allows you to have the flexibility of performing specific operations on each entity, so you'd better go with separate ones.

Okay, thanks for your answer!
